# MySQL random empty string as column value

Tags: java, mysql

I've been setting up MySQL for a Minecraft server overall plugin and I have stored all data so far succefully using the same methods. Problem is when I want to check if the row was created, else create it, somehow in the way of doing this my row value gets corrupted from `null` (note it's a string with value null) to an empty String.

The table auchouse contains 2 field. id int(3) unique and items varchar(21000) default 'null'.

This is the stack trace that I get when I start with a fresh db.
Somehow VALUE OF ITEM  check gets called twice in which the 'null' value is lost. Would appriacte some help with this.

```
    [15:57:11] [Server thread/INFO]: [DivinityRealm] NOT REGISTERED
    [15:57:11] [Server thread/INFO]: [DivinityRealm] VALUE SET FOR IT 1
    [15:57:11] [Server thread/INFO]: [DivinityRealm] VALUE OF ITEM null
    [15:57:11] [Server thread/INFO]: [DivinityRealm] VALUE OF ITEM
    [15:57:11] [Server thread/INFO]: [DivinityRealm] VALUE OF ITEM  NULL CHECK PASS$

[15:57:11] [Server thread/INFO]: [DivinityRealm] ITEMS VALUE
```

Error start(DiivinityRealm.java):

```
AuctionHouse au = null;
int count = 1;
do
{
    au = new AuctionHouse(count);
    au.update();
    for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if(p.getOpenInventory().getTitle().contains("Auction House")
                && Integer.parseInt(p.getOpenInventory().getTitle().split(" ")[2]) == au.getPage())
        {
            p.openInventory(au.getInventory());
        }
    }
    count++;
}while(!new AuctionHouse(count-1).isEmpty());
```

AuctionHouse.java:

```
public AuctionHouse(int pageNum)
{
    this.pageNum = pageNum;
    inv = DivinityRealm.getInstance().getServer().createInventory(null, 45, "Auction House " + pageNum)
    /* stuff*/
    register();

    getItems();
}
```

register method (AuctionHouse.java):

```
private void register()
{
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = DivinityRealm.connection.prepareStatement(AuctionTable.selectID);
        ps.setInt(1, pageNum);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(!rs.next()){
            DivinityRealm.getInstance().getLogger().info("NOT REGISTERED");
            PreparedStatement state = DivinityRealm.connection.prepareStatement(AuctionTable.insertEntryAllInfo);
            state.setInt(1, pageNum);
            state.executeUpdate();
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            DivinityRealm.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "VALUE SET FOR IT {0}", rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AuctionHouse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't register AucHouse", ex);
    }  
}
```

getItems() method(AuctionHouse.java):

```
private void getItems()
{
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = DivinityRealm.connection.prepareStatement(AuctionTable.selectItems);
        ps.setInt(1, pageNum);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            DivinityRealm.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "VALUE OF ITEM {0}", rs.getString(1));
            if(rs.getString(1).equals("null")){
                return;
            }
            DivinityRealm.getInstance().getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "VALUE OF ITEM {0} NULL CHECK PASSED", rs.getString(1));
            for(ItemStack item : deserialize(rs.getString(1)))
            {
                inv.addItem(item);
            }
        }
    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AuctionHouse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```